# CORS issue with AngularJs and Laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel, cors

I am using AngularJS as front-end and Laravel as back-end for handling API requests.

Also, Laravel constitute the administration panel for the website.

In order to overcome the CORS related challenges, I've added the following code in `routes.php` of Laravel:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'accept, content-type, x-xsrf-token, x-csrf-token');
```

But when we load administration panel it shows internal server error (GoDaddy server).

If we remove this the administration panel works fine, but the AngularJS part faces problem.

The API requests are blocked by the server.

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure those are the only headers in the request?

Comment: Does the administration panel loads with no error without your `header()` edits?

Comment: I doubt very much you're meant to make direct calls to `header`. Have a look at http://en.vedovelli.com.br/2015/web-development/Laravel-5-1-enable-CORS/

Comment: yes I am sure. The next lines are for handling get and post requests.




Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pages.login');
});

Route::get('user1', 'User@userlist')->name('user1');

Comment: yes administration panel loads with no error without this header.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this outside of Laravel, and set the headers instead with mod_headers:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#examples